How to reuse the 2 text fields from one form block to another in HTML and Spring boot?
I am new to HTML and Spring boot.
I have this html form index.html
I am trying to build a simple calculator with add/subtract and multiply functions.
I have 3 form blocks which points to 3 endpoints in Java spring boot.
I want to reuse the 2 text fields num1 and num2 in  form block for multiply in the add and subtract blocks.
How to do that in spring ?
Currently with my code the multiply works well however for the add & subtract the num1 and num2 values are passed as null and throws error.
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "num1" is null"
Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Simple Calculator</h1>

    <!-- Add form -->
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Subtract form -->
    <form action="/subtract" method="post">

        <br>
        <button type="submit">Subtract</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Multiply form -->
    <form action="/multiply" method="post">
        <label for="num1">Number 1:</label> <input type="text" id="num1"
            name="num1" th:value="${num1 != null ? num1 : ''}"> <label
            for="num2">Number 2:</label> <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2"
            th:value="${num2 != null ? num2 : ''}"> <br>
        <button type="submit">Multiply</button>

        <br> <br> <label for="result">Result:</label> <input
            type="text" id="result" th:value="${result}" readonly>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

--Java controller package
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String add(@RequestParam(value = "num1", required = false) Integer num1, @RequestParam(value = "num2", required = false) Integer num2, Model model) {
        int result = num1 + num2;
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        model.addAttribute("num1", num1);
        model.addAttribute("num2", num2);
        return "index"; // Return to the same page with updated data
    }

    @PostMapping("/subtract")
    public String subtract(@RequestParam(value = "num1", required = false) Integer num1, @RequestParam(value = "num2", required = false) Integer num2, Model model) {
        int result = num1 - num2;
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        model.addAttribute("num1", num1);
        model.addAttribute("num2", num2);
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/multiply")
    public String multiply(@RequestParam(value = "num1", required = false) Integer num1, @RequestParam(value = "num2", required = false) Integer num2, Model model) {
        int result = num1 * num2;
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
        model.addAttribute("num1", num1);
        model.addAttribute("num2", num2);
        return "index";
    }
}


th:value attribute only sets the value of the input field when rendering the form.
th:field both binds the form input to the model and automatically handles setting and retrieving values.

Thanks a lot @CodingCossack. I tried that but i got the below error for all 3 functions add/subtract and multiply.
I think still the num1 and num2 are passed as null even when i enter 10 and 5 respectively.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "num1" is null
I also tried like this but the same error was encountered.

 
Add

Don't use th:value here use th:field instead.

i rushed my initial answer. Made some edits which hopefully work for you.
